# Basic Pumping Lemma proof doesn't make sense

Tags: pumping-lemma

Proving that a^n b^n, n >= 0, is non-regular.
Using the string a^p b^p.

Every example I've seen claims that y can either contain a's, b's, or both.  But I don't see how y can contain anything other than a's, because if y contains any b's, then the length of xy must be greater than p, which makes it invalid.

Conversely, for examples such as:

www, w is {a, b}*, the string used is a^p b a^p b a^p b.  In the proofs I've seen, it claims that y cannot contain anything other than a's, for the reason I stated above.  Why is this different?

Also throwing in another question:

Describe the error in the following "proof" that 0* 1* is not a regular language. (An
error must exist because 0* 1* is regular.) The proof is by contradiction. Assume
that 0* 1* is regular. Let p be the pumping length for 0* 1* given by the pumping
lemma. Choose s to be the string OP P. You know that s is a member of 0* 1*, but
a^p b^p cannot be pumped. Thus you have a contradiction. So 0* 1* is not regular.

I can't find any problem with this proof.  I only know that 0*1* is a regular language because I can construct a DFA.

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pumping lemma states that for a regular language *L*:

> for all strings *s* greater than *p* there exists a subdivision *s=xyz* such that:
>
> 1. For all *i*, *xy<sup>i</sup>z* is in *L*;
> 2. *|y|>0*; and
> 3. *|xy|<p*.

Now the claim that *y* can only contain *a*'s or *b*'s originates from the **first** item. Since if it contained both *a*'s and *b*'s, with *i=2*, this would result in a string of the form *aa...abb...baa...b*, etc. That's what the statement wants to say.

The third part indeed, makes it obvious that *y* can only contain *a*'s. In other words, what the textbooks say is **a conclusion derived from the first item**.

Finally if you combine 1., 2. and 3., one reaches contradiction, because we know *y* must contain at least one character (2.), the string can only contain *a*'s. Say *y* contains *k* *a*'s. If we would "pump" this with *i=2*, the result is that we generate a string:

*s'=xy<sup>2</sup>z=a<sup>p+k</sup>b<sup>p</sup>*

We know however that *s'* **is not part of L**, which it should be by 1., so we reach inconsistency.

You can thus only make the proof work by **combining the three items**. It's not enough to know that *y* consist only out of *a*'s: that doesn't result in contradiction. It's because there is **no subdivision** available that satisfies all three constraints simultaneously.

---

About your second question. In that case, *L* looks different. You can't reuse the proof of *a^nb^n* **because *L* is perfectly happy if the string contains more *a*'s**. In other words, you can't find a contradiction. In other words, the **last item of the proof fails**. As long as *y* contains only one type of characters - regardless of its length - it can satisfy all three constraints.